# Multiple HTMl5 canvas elements generated by javascript not appearing (Works fine with a single element)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm relatively new to Javascript and i'm trying to generate multiple canvas elements on the same page to use as a "rating" display for products. (My javascript draws a number of stars)

This works fine when a product search results only returns one product (canvas element) however when there are multiple products, the canvas elements don't even appear on the page or the HTML itself.

Heres my code (I use AJAX search but i've stripped out most of it for readability, sorry if theres any syntax errors):

Search.js

```
function doRatings(avgRating, results){
        /* Print search */
        var canvas = new Array();
        resultsHTML = '';
        for(i=0;i<results.length;i++){
                resultsHTML = resultsHTML +  '<div id="AvgRating' + i + '"></div> <p>Under canvas</p>';                 
            }
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '<div class="section group">' + resultsHTML + '</div>';

            if(avgRating > 0){
                canvas[i] = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas[i].width  = 240;
                canvas[i].height = 20;
                canvas[i].id = i;

                drawRating(canvas[i], avgRating);
                document.getElementById("AvgRating" + i).appendChild(canvas[i]);
            }
}
```

DrawStars.js

```
function drawRating(canvas, avgRating){

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Start star loop
for(var s=0; s<avgRating; s++){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    ctx.stokeStyle = 'black';

    //Work out the angles between each vertex
    var a = (2 * Math.PI) / 10; //5 inside and outside angles 
    var radius = 10; //Determins the size of the stars

    //Determine the positioning to draw the start based upon the interation of the loop and the size of the star
    var starXY = [((s*(radius * 2 + 4)) + radius), radius];

    ctx.beginPath();

    //Begin drawing loop for star
    for(var i = 11; i != 0; i--){
        var r = radius*(i % 2 + 1) / 2;
        var o = a * i;
        ctx.lineTo((r * Math.sin(o)) + starXY[0], (r * Math.cos(o)) + starXY[1]);
    }

    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
}}
```

Comment: when you append canvas[i] should it be document.getElementById("AvgRating" + i).appendChild(canvas[i]); rather than "AvgRating" + ID

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, that was just an error created when trimming the code to put on here. ID usually refers to the ID of the product.

Comment: canvas[i] creation is not in a loop so only one created.

Answer (score 0):

Adding loop to the canvas creation completes process - see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XxexL/)

```
function doRatings(avgRating, results){
        /* Print search */
        var canvas = new Array();
        resultsHTML = '';
        for(i=0;i<results.length;i++){
                resultsHTML = resultsHTML +  '<div id="AvgRating' + i + '"></div> <p>Under canvas</p>';                 
            }
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '<div class="section group">' + resultsHTML + '</div>';
       for(i=0;i<results.length;i++){
            if(avgRating > 0){
                canvas[i] = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas[i].width  = 240;
                canvas[i].height = 20;
                canvas[i].id = i;

                drawRating(canvas[i], avgRating);
                document.getElementById("AvgRating" + i).appendChild(canvas[i]);
            }
      }
}
```